# Получаю ошибку "Error converting data type varchar to bigint." SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
  #dp_all.RegistrationNumber AS 'номер устройства',
  #dp_all.DeviceLocation AS 'Номер ТС',
  MAX(#card_transactions.timestamp) AS 'дата валидации',
  #dp_all.LastVersionReadTime AS 'дата связи'
FROM
  #dp_all
  INNER JOIN #card_transactions ON
    #dp_all.RegistrationNumber like '%' + #card_transactions.device_reg_no  
WHERE
  #dp_all.DeviceLocation  is not null
GROUP BY
  #dp_all.RegistrationNumber,
  #dp_all.DeviceLocation,
  #dp_all.LastVersionReadTime
ORDER BY
  #dp_all.DeviceLocation
```

Где:

- RegistrationNumber -bigint,
- DeviceLocation - nvarchar,
- LastVersionReadTime - datetime,
- derice_reg_no - bigint.

Comment: А какой тип у `#card_transactions.timestamp`?

Comment: @Akina, Тип данных - datetime

Comment: Упс, не посмотрел... проблема вот тут: `ON #dp_all.RegistrationNumber like '%' + #card_transactions.device_reg_no`. Конвертируйте явно оба поля в varchar, если хотите сравнивать их как строки. Или используйте математические операции для сравнения их как чисел.

Comment: @Akina можно поподробнее? Эти поля bigint

Comment: Правильно. А оператор LIKE работает исключительно с строками. Кстати, а эти два поля не должны быть просто равны? ну так, чисто случайно...

Comment: @Akina, нет, одно поле включает другое, но перед этим еще идут цифры. чем мне сравнивать? в одном поле 1155, во втором 565656(1155)

Comment: *во втором 565656(1155)* В BIGINT? что, правда? да ладно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая штука [Data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Именно из-за приоритетов вы получаете ошибку при сравнении, уже неявно приобразованной строки с bigint значением.

Второй момент, сравнивать эти поля стоит тогда когда они оба будут одного типа. Преведите первый в varchar(n)/nvarchar(n) и второй с помощью [CAST или CONVERT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) и сравнивайте вашим подходом наздоровье.

Пример условия:

```
ON convert(nvarchar,#dp_all.RegistrationNumber) like '%' + convert(nvarchar,#card_transactions.device_reg_no)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Если мой ответ решил вашу пролему, отметьте его как верный, поставив галочку.